Problems with spawning player after death
i'm trying to create spawner for my player but have some problems with it.
That's my code below
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    

    [SerializeField] private GameObject playerPrefab;
    private GameObject currentPlayer;
    [SerializeField] Vector2 respawnPoint;
    [SerializeField] private Text playerLivesText;
    static public bool playerAlive;


   

    private void Start()
    {

        playerLivesText.text = Player.playerLives.ToString();
        playerAlive = true;

    }

    

    private void Update()
    {
        
        LoseGame();

        if (!playerAlive) 
        {
            RespawnPoint();
            
        }
    }

    private void RespawnPoint()
    {
       if(playerPrefab != null)
       {
            playerPrefab = currentPlayer;
            currentPlayer = Instantiate(playerPrefab, respawnPoint, Quaternion.identity);
            playerAlive = true;
       }
       
       
    }

I expect that this code will work like , when player died he will be respawned on respawnPoint but insted this , PlayerPrefab always missing in the inspector and Unity can't respawn my player. Because i have "Missing Reference" error, ArgumentException: The Object you want to instantiate is null or nothing happening but player still not respawning.
I can't understand how i can assign my player again in player prefab after his first death.

well do you Destroy it somewhere (probably in LoseGame which you didn't share)? Why do you set playerPrefab = currentPlayer; ?

playerPrefab = currentPlayer; if you've destroyed your player, you will be setting it to an invalid option.. why is it being set to currentplayer?

@derHugo
yes , i use Destroy() to kill my player on the scene. And , answering for you second question , i thought that if i will write like that , unity automatically assign player again and all it will work , but i was wrong.

well you probably should just remove that line ... you want a fresh clone of the prefab and then correctly store the reference of that clone in currentPlayer

@derHugo
but i can't understand how i can get reference , i gues that's my main problem

@BugFinder cuz i thought that it will work but i was wrong. And now im trying to understand how i can fix it

your prefab should be something living in the assets ... otherwise you would want to create a clone before you Destroy the original one .... but then again I wonder why would you destroy it at all ... you could just reuse the existing instance instead

you must delete this line: playerPrefab = currentPlayer; and make sure you set playerPrefab field in the inspector with the prefab from the Project Window, not the prefab from the Hierarchy.
